# Accessing locally stored (hidden from user, under library) file in iOS

Tags: ios

Here is the `NSURL` object that I am using for creating and accessing important configuration file on iOS with features:

- hidden from user
- not user generated file (storing configuration related to user)
- not temp or cache (not possible to create later with existing data)
- must be backed up by iCloud/iTunes

  ```
  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                           NSLibraryDirectory,
                           NSUserDomainMask,
                           YES) objectAtIndex:0]
  stringByAppendingString:@"/important.txt"]];
  ```

---

As suggested in [FileSystemOverview (developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), I am storing this file under `Library`.
Maybe better way is storing it under `Library/Application Support`.

Using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, which takes:

- [`enum NSSearchPathDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory)

  - `NSApplicationDirectory`
  - `NSDeveloperApplicationDirectory`
  - `NSLibraryDirectory`
  - `NSDeveloperDirectory`
  - `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`
  - ...
- [`enum NSSearchPathDomainMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDomainMask)

  - `NSUserDomainMask`
  - `NSLocalDomainMask`
  - `NSSystemDomainMask`
  - ...
- `BOOL expandTilde`

---

Is this the correct way of storing such a file?

There are couple of alternatives for `NSSearchPathDirectory` and `NSSearchPathDomainMask`.

Also what about the `expandTilde`, on iOS is it necessary?

Is there a better way of doing it, instead of creating path as a `NSString` using `objectAtIndex` and appending file name then converting it to `NSURL`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` would be my first choice for this.

But keep a few things in mind:

1. Unlike the "Documents" folder, the "Library/Application Support" folder doesn't exist in an iOS app sandbox by default so you must create the folder before trying to use it.
2. "Hidden from the user" only means that the user won't see it under normal circumstances. But the file is easily accessible by anyone with any technical knowledge.

You do want to pass `YES` for the `expandTilde` parameter so your app returns a proper path when you run the app in the simulator. On a real iOS device, it makes little difference.

Do not use `stringByAppendingString:` to create paths. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`.

```
NSString *appSupportPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [appSupportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"important.txt"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

You can get a direct `NSURL` using `NSFileManager`:

```
NSURL *appSupportURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [appSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"important.txt"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped :)